# How to write in Bash script 3-4 commits to launch different type of automated UI tests in CircleCI?

Tags: bash, automated-tests, circleci, automated-deploy

Before it was working for regression and sanity tests:

Inside config.yml file:

`- run: if (git log --format=%B -n 1 $CIRCLE_SHA1) | grep -iqF release; then cd <company_folder> && mvn clean && mvn test -e -X -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../../../chromedriver -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=regression.xml; else cd <company_folder> && mvn clean && mvn test -e -X -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../../../chromedriver -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=smoke.xml; fi`

When we added for 'debug' commit - all builds started failing. 
`- run: if (git log --format=%B -n 1 $CIRCLE_SHA1) | grep -iqF release; then cd <company_folder> && mvn clean && mvn test -e -X -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../../../chromedriver -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=regression.xml; elif (git log --format=%B -n 1 $CIRCLE_SHA1) | grep -iqF debug; then cd <company_folder> && mvn clean && mvn test -e -X -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../../../chromedriver -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=debug.xml; else cd <company_folder> && mvn clean && mvn test -e -X -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../../../chromedriver -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=smoke.xml; fi`

We want to make one commit 'Debug' for debugging failed tests, because we don't want to wait 1 hour until all tests will be completed.

Please Help.

Comment: This is too long to read as a one-liner - a script file would be much more maintainable.

Comment: @l0b0 this command inside config.yml file.